# Nested Eger loading- load multiple functions of same model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$data = User::with([
        'subscriptions.courses.chapters.topics',
    ])
        ->where('id', $student->id)
        ->first();
```

this code will return the user with his subscriptions,courses related to that subscription and chapters related to the course as well as topics in a chapter..
My doubt is can i load an extra function exercises(which is exercises in chapter) with this function..

please note:: exercises is related to chapter model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = User::with([
             'subscriptions.courses.chapters.topics',
             'subscriptions.courses.chapters.exercises'
        ])
        ->where('id', $student->id)
        ->first();
```

Comment: What if i need only the exercise count..?
`public function ExerciseCount(){
        return count($this->exercises()->get());
    }`
i wrote this function and called it with above code instead of exercises it return an error

`Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int`

Comment: You can count them after getting the results with [map](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) method of Laravel Collection